# Initialize object' properties from array - inline

Tags: typescript

Here is my array:

```
const a = ['one', 'two'] as const;
```

Here is my object type:

```
type T = {
    { [key in typeof a[number]]: number;
}
```

Expected result:

```
const r: T = {
    one: 0,
    two: 0
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
const z: T = a.map((prop) => [prop, 0]);
```

It returns:
*Type '(number | "one" | "two")[][]' is missing the following properties from type 'T': one, two(2739)*

Comment: `map` returns an array, not an object. You should pass the result of that map to `Object.fromEntries()`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good until that last part. That last part should be:

```
const z: T = a.reduce((obj, prop) => ({...obj, [prop]: 0}), {} as T);
```

We are reducing the 'a' array to an object, starting it out as an empty object of type T (since we know it will be populated at the end of the reduction), then the callback adds each property and sets it to 0.